# How to execute a command from C and terminate it

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have command like:

```
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -n -f 15 -r 1280x720" -o "./output_http.so -n -w ./www "
```

for streaming video through Ethernet. Currently I am running through terminal, and for exit I just press **Ctrl+c**. But I need to do this using c-code. Is it possible or any other method available ?.

Thanks.

Comment: Learn about [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) in [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and perhaps about [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically you can do what you need to do by using `fork()` and the `exec` family.

It may work like this:

```
 pid_t PID = fork();
 if(PID == 0) {
      execl("yourcommandhere");
      exit(1);
 }
 //do Whatever
 kill(PID, 15);  //Sends the SIGINT Signal to the process, telling it to stop.
```

`execl` (or any other member of the family, look here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl), will replace the current process with the process you're calling. This is the child process we created with fork. Fork returns '0' for the child process and the actual process ID of the child to the original process calling fork, which gives the original process control.

By calling `kill` and supplying `SIGINT` (15) you're telling the process with the specified PID (which you got from fork) to stop. `exit(1)` is necessary, because otherwise, if `execl` should fail, you'd have two processes doing the same thing at your hands. It's a failsafe.

I hope this helps.

Comment: After all this, call `waitpid(PID, NULL, 0);` to tell the kernel you're done with the child process handle.

Comment: Can I do this without exit(1), because I don't want exit my main program after kill.

Comment: @Haris The `exit` ONLY affects the child process, which is the mjpg_streamer software, but not the main process. As you can see, it is only called, if PID equals 0, which causes the main process to skip right over it, because `fork` returns the actual PID for that one.

Answer (score 1):

usaually we use **system("command");**

copy that Entire command  into **string** lets say **str**

```
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -n -f 15 -r 1280x720" -o "./output_http.so -n -w ./www "
```

Into string and then use

```
system(str); //in c code.
```

Comment: @Gangadhar Thing is, System freezes the program, since it waits for the process you just called to finish. Basically `system` calls: `fork()`, `execl()` and `wait()` in this order.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium , yes  Agreed, the way you suggested is works fine in this case. thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -n -f 15 -r 1280x720" -o "./output_http.so -n -w ./www "

pkill mjpg_stramer
```

you can invoke pkill using `system()`

Comment: You can put the & symbol at the end of the first command, so that it runs asynchronously - i.e. mjpg_streamer will run in the 'background' while your C program continues.

Answer (score 1):

when you executed with `system(./mjpg_streamer)`

A user process mjpg_streamer is created

You can kill this process again with `pkill(mjpg_streamer)`

Comment: No, the first call to `system` won't return while `mjpg_streamer` is still running.